# CollectionView scroll with button tap scrollToItem not working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I currently have a login and signup buttons labeled as 1 and 2. And underneath that, I have a collectionView with two cells (one for the login UI and one for register UI). When I click on the signup button(Label 2), I want to move the collectionView to the next cell.

I tried using the scrollToItem, but it does not do anything. Anyone know why?

```
 @objc private func didTapRegisterButton() {
        let i = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)
        self.onboardingCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: i, at: .right, animated: true)
  }
```

[image]

Comment: One really weird thing I found out is: If I am on the second collectionViewCell and click on button #2, It moves to the left. I don't know why though..The indexPath is item:1, section:0 (which should be the 2nd cell right?)...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My collectionView had isPagingEnabled property as true. The scrollToItem doesn't work if that is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll between two cells on button click then first you need to uncheck(disable) Scrolling Enabled property and check(enable) Paging Enabled property of collectionView. (*With this approach user can't scroll manually with swipe)*

On button first action,

```
if self.currentIndexPath == 0 {
   return
} else {
   self.currentIndexPath += 1
   self.yourCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: self.currentVisibleIndexPath, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

On button second action,

```
if self.currentIndexPath == 1 {
   self.currentIndexPath -= 1
   self.yourCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: self.currentVisibleIndexPath, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
} else {
   return
}
```

And declare global variable

```
var currentIndexPath: Int = 0
```

Comment: You can improve this approach without using any other variable <currentIndexPath>. Simply you can identify the currently selected state from the menu button (tabs) using UIButton's property called isSelected;